# Arreglo de Objetos en Java

Tags: java, array, object

Buen día, resulta que debo hacer un arreglo que pueda guardar tanto datos como int, String, boolean y a su vez cualquier otro tipo de Objeto que se le ingrese. Yo estaba usando el ArrayList ya que da la opción de guardar lo que sea en cada una de sus posiciones, pero resulta que tengo que hacerlo usando un arreglo convencional, solo que no se de que tipo hacerlo, si un int o un String. El hecho es que se tendrá que hacer un casting pero no se de que manera hacerlo para que vaya guardando lo que sea en sus posiciones. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Podrias mostrar algo de lo que intentaste? porque no un vector de objetos basico?

Comment: es decir Object[] datos = new Object[10];
¿Te refieres a eso?

Comment: Claro.. eso te genera algun problema? En realidad tu mayor problema va a ser despues saber que es cada cosa...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tratas de hacer es un poco tedioso ya que creando un arreglo de tipo Object podras almacenar todo tipo de objetos pero a la hora de recuperar esos objetos vas a tener que verificar que tipo de objeto es te puede ser de ayuda el operador instanceof.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] arreglo = new Object[3];
    arreglo[0] = new Integer(12);
    arreglo[1] = "Cadena";
    arreglo[2] = new Double(78.3);

    for (Object object : arreglo) {
        if(object instanceof String) {
            System.out.println((String) object);
        }else if(object instanceof Integer){
            System.out.println(((Integer)object) + 12);
        }else if(object instanceof Double) {
            System.out.println(((Double)object) + 78.3);
        }
    }

}

}
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Gracias! el código era realmente sencillo, me estaba complicando ;D

Answer (score 1):

Para almacenar datos tienes tantas clases en la propia librería de Java.util.

Como ya te han comentado puedes emplear un `Array` de `Object` o
por ejemplo, las estructras de datos más comunes:

1. [`ArrayList<Object>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
2. [`LinkedList<Object>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)
3. [`HashMap<K,Object>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)
4. [`TreeMap<K,Object>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Donde 'K' es el tipo de clave que quieras utilizar. Date cuenta que el valor de cada diccionario ha de ser de tipo Object, nada de valores primitivos, han de ser extensiones de Object como son los [siguientes](http://lineadecodigo.com/java/tipos-de-datos-objeto-en-java/):

- int -->Integer
- float-->Float
- boolean -->Boolean
- char -->Char

. Lo malo que tiene hacer esto, es que a la hora de obtener los datos almacenados has de preguntarle de qué tipo de objeto es mediante [`instanceOf()` o `getClass()`](http://www.forosdelweb.com/f45/como-saber-tipo-clase-objeto-499949/). 
¡NO ES RECOMENDABLE HACER ESTO! Cada objeto ha de estar en su "cajoncito".

*"Los calcetines van al cajón de los calcetines"*